# How can i read struct from a file?

Tags: c, file, struct, fread

```
struct Country{
    char name[50];
    float square;
    float quantityOfPeople;
};
```

```
 while (fread(&newRecord,sizeof(struct Country),1,fout)) {
        printf("hello\n");
        if (strcmp (countryName, newRecord.name) == 0) {
            printf("A record with requested name found and deleted.\n\n");
            found=1;
        } else {
            fwrite(&newRecord, sizeof(struct Country), 1, fp_tmp);
        }

    }
```

my file is

```
hjk
78.699997
799.900024

america
3432.300049
2323.199951

ghi
78.900002
89.000000

dmdmd
746234052608.000000
0.000000
```

In my file there is 4 records of country so it should print 4 times hellp, but it prints hello twice.
The main task is to remove the duplicate entry in the file.

Comment: note that your fread call reads (probably) 58 bytes (`sizeof(struct Country)`) and then puts them into the struct. So it will read hjk\n78.699997\n799.900024\n\namerica\n..... all the way up to 58 bytes, all into the one struct variable

Comment: @AndersK Yes i am writting it in different file

Comment: So you are trying to read text mode file into binary structure? That is never going to work with just single fread call. You need to parse the file and convert text data into binary format.

Comment: @user694733 can u explain ?

Comment: For example, in your file `78.699997` appears to be an text which is 9 characters long. In your structure `float square` is not text data type, but binary data type which is 4 bytes long. You cannot just blindly read that data from file to structure. You need to read file line by line into character array, and then convert that data to binary and store it in structure, each field one by one. You need `fgets`, not `fread`.

Comment: that file is text, you should be reading it with fscabf wabd writing it with fprintf

Answer (score 1):

`fread(&newRecord,sizeof(struct Country),1,fout)` is for reading binary data from a file.

OP's file is text based.

---

> How can i read struct from a file?

Open the file in text mode.

Form a helper function that reads 4 *lines* with 4x `fgets()` and then processes the lines for 1) country name, 2) some `double` (see `strod()`) 3) another `double` and 4) an optional empty line.

If all these pass, save in a `struct Country`

Return 1 for success, 0 for failure, `EOF` for nothing read.